# Emacs: how to trigger scroll when cursor is n-lines from top/bottom of screen?

Tags: emacs, scrolling

I'd like to trigger a scroll in emacs when my cursor gets within 4 lines from the top or bottom of the terminal.

My `.vimrc` file contains this line:

```
:set scrolloff=4
```

What do I add to `.emacs` to acheive the same?

PS. I promise not to add it with:

```
vi ~/.emacs
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `scroll-margin` will help -- look for it in the Emacs docs on [Textual Scrolling](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Textual-Scrolling.html).

Put this in your .emacs:

```
(setq scroll-margin 4)
```